# How long do new rotors take to break in?

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, rotor

I mounted [new rotors](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B09965LTM5) a week ago, and today they make a crunching noise just as terrible as on day one. It's a sound that makes you think a small rock is stuck between your pads, except there isn't. I did maybe 100km on the rotors, exclusively city rides with no significant descents, but I still feel like the crunching (which I've read is normal at the start) should have stopped by now.

What kind of break-in time is normal for new rotors? Should I be worried something is wrong?

Comment: Disc brakes are not my cup of tea, but I wonder if it's something to do with rotor and pad compatibility? Or maybe it's something like cassettes and chains, where it's not mandatory, but highly recommended, to replace the chain if replacing the cassette?

Comment: The bed-in process shouldn't take longer than 20 minutes. But you need to properly "bed-in" the brakes (information abound on this website and others about that process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now can say that in my case, it took 8 months and approximately 10000km, but finally my brakes as silent as disc brakes are supposed to be. I'd say about 40% of the noise went away during the first ~10 days, but the other 60% was extremely persistent and only really dwindled down during the last few weeks.

Brake pad changes didn't affect the noise at all, so I'm sure that the rotors actually were the cause. My best guess is that the factory saves some of the money on properly deburring the edges of all the holes in the brake surface, so the pads had to slowly grind their way down.

By the way, I live in a decently hilly city with a few steep descents, so the brakes got more than enough use. IIRC I used up 2.5 sets of pads since I mounted the rotors.

Comment: To future readers of this question -- your brakes should not take this long to bed in. 10 hard braking efforts (for front and rear individually) when pedaling around the block should get you ~90% of the way there.

Answer (score 3):

Rotors take only a short time to bed in, as Paul described in comments. However, you need to actively bed them in. This means you need to execute a few hard stops. You could drive up a hill with the bike, then coast down, and pull the brake levers hard a few times. Or sprint and then hard brake several times. I’m not sure if the rotors actually bed in if you just ride normally. Even if they did bed in, you’d be suffering from poor braking until they did so.

If I recall correctly, the symptom of unbedded rotors is lack of braking power. It’s not noise. Without being there, it’s impossible to be certain, but the noise you describe sounds more like there is actually some debris stuck to the pads. You could take the wheel out and perhaps wash that out with water or blow it out with compressed air.

Normally, I believe we usually wear the pads out before the rotors. So, if this is a relatively new bike, I am slightly surprised that you changed rotors but not pads. Ignore this if you actually measured your rotors and pads and the rotors are below the minimum thickness. However, if you had worn the pad material off completely, then when you brake, the bare metal pad holders are going to be scraping the rotors, which is bad for the rotors. I think this isn’t likely to be the case, but I wanted to warn you just on he off chance.

Comment: I have had sintered pads crumble a bit, giving a similar sort of noise and poor but not nonexistent braking (the market for BB5-compatible pads is dominated by cheap ones, sometimes too cheap, and I tried a few before I settled on a reliable brand)

Answer (score -1):

"they make a crunching noise just as terrible as on day one. It's a sound that makes you think a small rock is stuck between your pads"

This makes me think you have either contaminated pads, or you didn't "reset" pistons before replacing the new pads. Probably the latter...

Remove your pads, push pistons fully in, and reinstall again. If problem persists, try replacing them with the pads at back. If sound gone, it's contaminated pads. If there is still noise, maybe it's time to bleed your front brakes.

Most of the time, those noises are a manifestation of not enough brake force.